# Sprockets::FileOutsidePaths error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am new to ruby on rails and following the the book `Agile Web Development with Rails 4`.
I have set the path of the css as follows

```
<head>
<title>Depot</title>
<%= stylesheet_link_tag  "/home/abuzar/Desktop/ruby/work/depot/public/styles/depot.css"%>
<%= javascript_include_tag :defaults %>
<%= csrf_meta_tags %>
</head>
```

I checked the weblink for [stylesheet_link_tag](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/AssetTagHelper/stylesheet_link_tag) and expanded path
My question is how to set the path to different location
Now the app is giving the following error

```
   Showing /home/abuzar/Desktop/ruby/work/depot/app/views/layouts/application.html.erb where line #5 raised:

   /home/abuzar/Desktop/ruby/work/depot/public/stylesheets/depot.css isn't in paths:`
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Files in the `public` directory can be referenced by a relative path.

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag  "styles/depot.css" %>
```

However, the `public` directory is an **unconventional** location for a stylesheet.  `app/assets/stylesheets` is the convention.

> In previous versions of Rails, all assets were located in
>   subdirectories of public such as images, javascripts and stylesheets.
>   With the asset pipeline, the preferred location for these assets is
>   now the app/assets directory. Files in this directory are served by
>   the Sprockets middleware.
>
> Assets can still be placed in the public hierarchy. Any assets under
>   public will be served as static files by the application or web
>   server. You should use app/assets for files that must undergo some
>   pre-processing before they are served.
>
> http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#how-to-use-the-asset-pipeline